# Is it possible to deploy Apache Nifi on WildFly?

Tags: wildfly, apache-nifi

Our team works with WildFly as a standart application server. We would like to add Apache Nifi to our set of technologies. The problem is that according to this comment (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nifi-dev/201605.mbox/%3C3B44DF8F-B111-4EAC-8D5F-6BEE8557584F%40gmail.com%3E) Apache Nifi by the time of writing couldn't be deployed on WildFly. It could onlt be started with embedded server.

A question is - is it possible to deploy Apache Nifi to some application server now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NiFi architecture and composition has not changed in a material way from the linked thread to support running in an application server.  NiFi is designed as, and remains, a standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

No, Apache NIFI Architecture tightly coupled to embedded server. and does it meant be to do deploy with other webservers